# Titanium- Make "more" button to view full label text

Tags: iphone, titanium

How would one make the "more" button to see a full description (like in the app store) using Appcelerator Titanium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would manipulate the height of the label.height on button click event. helpful enough?